# How to reflect any Adds, Removes, field changes immediately in the UI for Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I am having a real problem in getting changes to my Observable Collection (Adds, Removes, Field changes) to be immediately show in my TableView UI.

I wrote a small program to test functionality. It works but does not imme4diately reflect changes it waits until all Adds, Removes, Changes have completed before it shows the results.

I want it to show each change as it occurs. i.e., if I add a record it immediately shows the change. The UI should scroll down the screen showing adds as they occur.

In my code I have included sleeps between adds, removes and changes to prove this.

What do I need to do to make all changes (adds, removes, field changes) to be immediately reflected?

Attached is some code that I have.

```
namespace ObservableTest
{
  internal static class Common
  {
    public static ObservableCollection OC = new ObservableCollection();

    public static void AddRecords(int HowMany = 100)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < HowMany; i++)
        {
            OC.Add(new TestObservable("StringData " + i.ToString(), i));
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveRecords(int HowMany = 5)
    {
        var data = OC.ToList();
        foreach(var field in data)
        {
            if(field.IntField < HowMany)
            {
                OC.Remove(field);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ChangeRecords(int HowMany = 5)
    {
        var data = OC.ToList();
        foreach(var field in data)
        {
            field.StringField += " C";
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
        }
    }
}
public class TestObservable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    { this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }

    private string stringField = "";
    private int intField = 0;

    public TestObservable(string StringField, int IntField)
    {
        this.stringField = StringField;
        this.intField = IntField;
    }
    public string StringField
    {
        get { return stringField; }
        set
        {
            if (this.stringField != value)
            {
                this.stringField = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("StringField");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public int IntField
    {
        get { return intField; }
        set
        {
            if (this.intField != value)
            {
                this.intField = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("IntField");
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the viewmodel you used for your view? What is xaml code like? Your question is not clear

Comment: How does the sleep allow the UI to update? Is this being done on a background thread?

Comment: If the methods are called on the main thread, `Thread.Sleep` does not allow the UI update, but instead blocks the UI.

Comment: Remove Thread.Sleep(1000); from your code and the UI will update properly. See the comment from Klaus Gitter to understand what Thread.Sleep(1000);  does. When you sleep can you paint a picture? Same applies to Thread.Sleep(1000); . The name or the semantic meaning of Thread.Sleep is chosen for a reason.

Comment: @BionicCode - This will possible confuse the OP. He's expecting to the see the results of the loop update - which won't happen simply by removing the `Sleep`.

Comment: TC immediately writes that this is a test program for testing functionality.
In real code, there won't be any Sleep.
This is a test emulation of lengthy synchronous operations.
There is not even a hint from TC about the issue of the correct implementation of the delay.

Comment: @EldHasp IT IS NOT ABOUT THE CORRECT IMPLEMENTATION OF A DELAY! The whole point is that his synchronous code (whether it is the mocking Thread.Sleep or "real synchronous code" will block the UI thread, which  leads to the result that the UI thread has no free resources to render changes in the view. That is why he currently has to wait until all blocking operations are completed. It is the synchronous nature that give the troubles. It is not about Thread.Sleep or Task.Dealy. It is about synchronous vs asynchronous. It is about thread blocking vs non thread blocking.

Comment: Please clarify why you use `Sleep`?
As I suggested (from this assumption I gave an answer), this is an **EMULATION of long-term executed synchronous commands**.
But this opinion, as it turned out, is not shared by everyone.
Some suggest that the meaning of your question is: **"How to properly implement latency without UI lags?"**
For a correct answer, you need to clarify the meaning of the question you asked.

Comment: We agree upon that Thread.Sleep is to simulate synchronous code. And I explained many many times that Thread.Sleep is not the issue. It is THE SYNCHRONOUS NATURE OF THE CODE: SYNCHRONOUS CODE WILL ALWAYS BLOCK THE THRHEAD IT EXECUTES ON IN A WAY THAT THE EXECUTING THREAD IS NOT FREE TO DO OTHER WORK IN PARALLEL E.G. RENDER THE UI. Please. Your words: _" long-term executed synchronous commands"_ - and this is exactly the problem. It should be:  long-term executed **asynchronous** commands!!!

Comment: @BionicCode, then I do not understand you all the more.
In my answer, I showed that all operations (including preparatory operations before making changes) must be transferred to the task and in the UI thread, you only need to update the collection itself.
What did not suit you in my answer?

Comment: @EldHasp Your answer moves collection modificattion to the dispatcher while you keep on blocking the UI thread. But you should get rid of any UI blocking code (if it is long running). That is why .NET offers the task library. That is why C# offers async/await. This concept (which you will find in other languages too) allows us to write code that can executue on the UII thread without blocking it.

Comment: You don't want to block the UI thread as it will have immediate effect on the UI which will stop rendering which leads to a "freezed" UI, where all sequential updates occure to happen at once as soon as the thread has free resources again.

Comment: @EldHasp There are many more issues with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute the blocking code  asynchronously.

To convert your example to async, simply replace the blocking `Thread.Sleep` with the non blocking `Task.Delay`.

The point is that Thread.Sleep does block the UI thread. While the UI thread is sleeping, it can't do anything else like rendering changes.
Thread.Sleep aside: when your blocking (synchronous) code executes asynchronouosly, you allow the UI thread to remain responsive. The UI thread will be able to render the changes in your view while executing the asynchronous code.

```
internal static class Common
{
  public static ObservableCollection<TestObservable> OC = new ObservableCollection<TestObservable>();

  public static async Task AddRecords(int HowMany = 100)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < HowMany; i++)
    {
      OC.Add(new TestObservable("StringData " + i.ToString(), i));
      await Task.Delay(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
    }
  }

  public static async Task RemoveRecords(int HowMany = 5)
  {
    var data = OC.ToList();
    foreach (var field in data)
    {
      if (field.IntField < HowMany)
      {
        OC.Remove(field);
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
      }
    }
  }

  public static async Task ChangeRecords(int HowMany = 5)
  {
    var data = OC.ToList();
    foreach (var field in data)
    {
      field.StringField += " C";
      await Task.Delay(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the question, `Sleep` means a large number of different operations performed in synchronous code.
To emulate their execution with waiting, the result of using `Delay` is not enough.
Read carefully the essence of the question.

Comment: And I say you should convert your synchronous code to asynchronous code. `Task.Delay` does exactly this. Task.Delay "emulates" asynchronously executed operations. The whole point is to not block the UI if you want the UI to remain responsive i.e. update in time.

Comment: I perfectly understand the difference between Sleep and Delay.
But TC doesn't ask a question about it.
In fact, you have invented a different question for yourself and answer this question of yours.

Comment: _"I wrote a small program to test functionality. It works but does not imme4diately reflect changes it waits until all Adds, Removes, Changes have completed before it shows the results."_ Have you read that? He says _" It works but does not imme4diately reflect changes it waits until all Adds, Removes, Changes have completed before it shows the results."_ - this is due to the blocked UI thread. I think I have understood the question quite correctly.

Comment: The program checks the functionality of what?
How to make a delay correctly?
Or how to correctly execute a large number of commands that take a significant amount of time?
In real code, both Sleep and Delay are meaningless.
And they just need to be removed.
`Sleep` makes sense only in the case of use **TO EMULATE** long-term synchronous operations.
What can help to test and/or emulate `Delay`, it does not occur to me.

Comment: Please go back again and think about it. Forget the emulation thing. Ok, in your world Task.Delay emulates asynchronous code. In "real code" you would convert your synchronous thread blocking code to asynchronous non-blocking code. You must agree on this if  think about it again. In your own words: Thread.Sleep is meant to simulate, so is Task.Delay. Just get rid of the synchronous operations **if you want to keep the thread responsive during its execution**.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use asynchronous methods.
All long-running work should take place in tasks executed on the thread pool.
And only the direct change of the collection bound in WPF View should happen on the main thread of the application.
To perform operations on the main thread, you first need to get it, and then pass it method delegates to put it in the execution queue.
After placing in the queue, you can wait for the completion of their execution (as in my example), but you can also skip waiting and immediately continue further processing.
It depends on the algorithm you are implementing and the need to process the result.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace ObservableTest
{
    public static class Common
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<TestObservable> OC { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<TestObservable>();

        public static Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; } = Application.Current.Dispatcher;

        private static readonly Action<TestObservable> AddRecord = OC.Add;
        private static readonly Func<TestObservable, bool> RemoveRecord = OC.Remove;
        private static readonly Action<int, TestObservable> ReplaceRecord = (index, item) => OC[index] = item;

        // Synchronous method. It is undesirable to call it from the UI thread.
        public static void AddRecords(int howMany = 100)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            {
                TestObservable test = new TestObservable("StringData " + i.ToString(), i);
                DispatcherOperation operation = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(AddRecord, test);
                DispatcherOperationStatus status = operation.Wait();
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
            }
        }

        // Asynchronous method. It can be called from the UI thread.
        public static async void AddRecordsAsync(int howMany = 100)
            => await Task.Run(() => AddRecords(howMany));

        public static void RemoveRecords(int howMany = 5)
        {
            var data = OC.ToList();
            foreach (TestObservable field in data)
            {
                if (field.IntField < howMany)
                {
                    DispatcherOperation operation = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(RemoveRecord, field);
                    DispatcherOperationStatus status = operation.Wait();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
                }
            }
        }
        public static async void RemoveRecordsAsync(int howMany = 5)
            => await Task.Run(() => RemoveRecords(howMany));

        public static void ChangeRecords(int howMany = 5)
        {
            var data = OC.ToList();
            foreach (TestObservable field in data)
            {
                field.StringField += " C";
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep to see outcome in UI
            }
        }
        public static async void ChangeRecordsAsync(int howMany = 5)
            => await Task.Run(() => ChangeRecords(howMany));
    }
}
```